# Close fancybox by clicking a class within the box

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to get my modal box (#newspopup) closed when clicking on a button (`<div class="visitwebsitebtn">Click here to enter</div>`)? I tried

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.visitwebsitebtn', function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
    });

    </script>
```

but without success. Any thoughts on this? Many thanks

Fancy code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout( function() {$('#newspopup').trigger('click'); },2000);

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 0.0001 });
    $('#newspopup').fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
            }
        }
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Script to close:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.visitwebsitebtn', function() {
$.fancybox.close();
});

</script>
```

Box:

```
   <div id="newspopup" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Latest news</h2>
    <p>blablabla</p>
    <div class="visitwebsitebtn">Click here to enter</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: **BEWARE** that your selector `#newspopup` is both, the fancybox trigger and the fancybox content itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target === $('.visitwebsitebtn')[0]) {
        $.fancybox.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to bind the `click` handler inside a fancybox (`afterShow`) callback

```
$('#newspopup').fancybox({
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
            }
        }
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        $(".visitwebsitebtn").on("click", function(){
            $.fancybox.close();
        });
    }
});
```

... assuming that the button with `class="visitwebsitebtn"` is inside your `#newspopup` container.

No need to bind an extra `click` to `$(document)`.

Comment: Thanks JFK - Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Why dont  you attach your click handlers like this ?

```
 $(".visitwebsitebtn").click(function() {
        $.fancybox.close();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that does not work in my case (might be due to the fact that i'm using v2 of fancybox?)

Comment: @Greg : that doesn't have anything to do with the version of fancybox you are using but how the handler is bound to the selector, which it should be in a delegated form.